# Sticky-Kit doesnot work with Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, sticky

I have a 3 column layout where all 3 cols are to be sticky so that they all scroll, but then each of them stick to the bottom as the content in that column finishes. Am using sticky-kit (https://github.com/leafo/sticky-kit)

This works fine with Bootstrap 3.3.5 / 3.3.7. 
as you can see in this fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/741anks0/1/

But come bootstrap 4.0, and things start breaking.

**[Edit_01 Start]**
By breaks, I mean that :

1. Stick_in_parent does not work. When the page is scrolled, none of the columns stick at the bottom. (Kindly check the fiddle).
2. If I add the css **align-self:flex-start** to the columns that should stick, there is a strange behaviour which you can see in the jsfiddle

**[Edit_01 End]**

I think the sticky lib is unable to calculate the heights of the columns, for which I did try using flex-start :

```
    .stickem{  align-self:flex-start; }
```

But still no joy. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here is a fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/2cz8c1jn/27/
If you uncomment the line /*align-self:flex-start;*/ in the JSFiddle (CSS) , you should see how the sticky-scroll on the columns break.

Comment: Your question is far from being clear.

Comment: I've edited the question with more details.